# How to cast selected TListViewItem from "OnItemClick" event, on assigning to multiple buttons?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

i have an application with 2 TButton, 1 TListView. I would like display the value or content(Text) of TListViewItem inside the TButton(s) in a way that the content of the first TButton can't be the same with the 2nd one.
Steps =>>

1. When I click on the 1st TButton, I can select the Item text in the TListView and save it as new TButton text.
2. When I click on the 2nd TButton, I can select another item text in the same TListView, and it is saved as Text in the 2nd TButton.

My code:

```
....
  ListView1: TListView;
  Base: TButton;
  Hypo: TButton;
....

procedure TMainForm.BaseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ListView1.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TMainForm.HypoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ListView1.Visible := True;
end;    

procedure TMainForm.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
   const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
   if Assigned(ListView1.Selected) and Assigned(Base.OnClick) then
   begin
      Base.Text := TListViewItem(ListView1.Selected).Text;
   end else
   if Assigned(ListView1.Selected) and Assigned(Hypo.OnClick) then
   begin
      Hypo.Text := TListViewItem(ListView1.Selected).Text;
   end;
   ListView1.Visible := False;
end;
```

I used LiveBindings to fill the TListView; when i run the app and select one item it works but it's displaying the same value/content in both TLabels
[image: TListViewwith2labels]

Comment: Well, you are assigning the same text to both labels, are you not?

Comment: That's the result of my code. But what i want is to assign different text to the labels from the same listview. I dig through embaracadero's doc but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have 2 selected items, then you have to iterate through the whole list view

```
procedure TForm3.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var elvitem : TListViewItem;
    i,n : integer;
begin
n:=0;
for i:=0 to ListView1.ItemCount-1 do
 begin
   if ListView1.Items[i].Purpose=TListItemPurpose.None then // it's an item 
    begin
      if ListView1.Items[i].Checked then
      begin
       inc(n);
      case n of
        1 : base.text:=ListView1.Items[i].Text;
        2 : begin
              hypo.text:=ListView1.Items[i].Text;
              break; // don't search more
            end;
      end;
      end;
    end;
 end;
```

Here item 2 and 8 are selected with this code

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Listview1.Items[2].Checked:=True;
Listview1.Items[8].Checked:=True;
end;
```

[image: here item 2 and 8 are selected]

Comment: i'll try, i think it should be `for i:=0 to ListView1.ItemCount -1` instead of `for i:=0 to ListView1.ItemCount`. Right?

Comment: Right, sorry for mistake, assuming there was always 2 selected items it was not a problem but yes it's `for i:=0 to ListView1.ItemCount -1` 
(corrected in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction, if your listview is livebinded then why don't you use livebindings to link your 2 labels ?

Second one is your code, you use Selected when you have the AItem parameter
so

```
procedure TMainForm.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
   const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  Base.Text:= AItem.text;
  Hypo.Text:= AItem.detail;
  ListView1.Visible := False;
end;
```

should be sufficient if it is not a DynamicAppearance type.

Comment: Thanks @sergegirard for your answer, but i think you misunderstood my request, even though i use `AItem`. Suppose that my `TListView` is populated with items (Text+details), I want my 1st label to display the selected AItem.Text and the 2nd label another selected AItem.Text of the same `TListView`. the fact is that i don't know how to proceed and livebindings allows me to link `SelectedValue` table and that's fall in the same result = the same AItem.Text is displayed on Both labels.

Comment: Ah ok, but this means you have only 2 selected items ?

Comment: yes i have to select 2 items!

Comment: Ok, so I wrote something in my French blog about Listview and selection
https://www.developpez.net/forums/blogs/138527-sergiomaster/b8177/fmx-selection-delements-tlistview/ (googletrad should be your friend I guess).
As I remember, but it was in 2019, there is no list of ItemsChecked (except if you manage to have one ;)  chapter 1.4). 
A solution should be to browse the listview and get the two item.checked elements.

But I suspect (from image) what you want is n-1 and n+1 text not selected ones.

Comment: But I suspect (from image) what you want is n-1 and n+1 text not selected ones.
If so, then this code works
<br>
procedure TForm3.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
if AItem.Index=0
   then MinusOne.Text:=''
   else MinusOne.Text:=ListView1.Items[AItem.Index-1].Text;
if AItem.Index=ListView1.ItemCount-1
   then PlusOne.Text:=EmptyStr
   else PlusOne.Text:=ListView1.Items[AItem.Index+1].Text;
end;

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. i tried but it doesn't seem to suit me. what i tried is to move the `if Assigned(ListView1.Selected)` inside each labels. but the problem is that it doesn't keep the selected item once i clikcked to select another item.